# Registering 2 handlers to same route but different query params

Tags: java, rest, jakarta-ee, jax-rs

I am trying to add 2 handlers to my REST API on the same route but with different query params. I want the `/getStudents` route to return all students while the `/getStudents?studentName=SomeName` should only return the details for the given student. But when I run this, only the second function is run even if I go on the `/getStudents` route. I have the following code:

```
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public class StudentService {

    private StudentDAO studentDAO;

    @GET
    @Path("getStudents")
    public List<Student> getStudents() {
        return studentDAO.getStudents();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("getStudents")
    public Student getStudentById(@QueryParam("studentName") String studentName) {
        return studentDAO.getStudentsById(studentName);
    }

    public void setStudentDAO(StudentDAO studentDAO) {
        this.studentDAO = studentDAO;
    }

    public StudentDAO getStudentDAO() {
        return studentDAO;
    }

}
```

I'm new to Java and J2EE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Steve, you should uniquely identify your resources, but if you really want it you can inject @Context under same path and return all or just one student based on query param:

```
@GET
@Path("getStudents")
public Response getStudents(@Context HttpServletRequest request){

           if (request.getParameterMap().isEmpty()) {
               // return all students in Reponse
           } else {
               String queryParam = request.getQueryString();
               // check queryParam and return on student in Response
           }


    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can change `getStudentById` as follows:

```
@GET
@Path("getStudents/{studentName}")
public Student getStudentById(@PathParam("studentName") String studentName) {
    return studentDAO.getStudentsById(studentName);
}
```

which will allow JAX-RS to disambiguate the method calls.

This means the client will need to GET

```
http://somehost/somecontext/getStudents/Fred%20%Bloggs
```

instead of

```
http://somehost/somecontext/getStudents?studentName=Fred%20%Bloggs
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, but is there a way to do it using the query params?

Comment: It's my understanding that this is not possible using JAX-RS. FWIW, in English we would normally `@Path("getStudent")` when the student id is provided because this is the singular (returns one student) as opposed to `@Path("getStudents")` being the plural (returns many students).